# Jmeter. TestScriptRecorder requires the certificate

Tags: jmeter

I set the certificate generated by jmeter in the trusted root certificate authorities, but everything TestScriptRecorder all the same asks to set the certificate.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lrdf.png)

Comment: It's not an error!! just click ok here. Then you will be able to record your script. :)

Comment: I set up a proxy server in Internet Explorer, I click start, I try to transfer according to pages on the browser, I click stop. In Recording Controller not one request isn't displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The fastest and the easiest way of configuring JMeter for recording is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature.

   From JMeter main menu select File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create

   [image: JMeter Template Creation]

   Default port for HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder originated from template is **8888**
2. Make sure you have "Use the same proxy server for all protocols" box CHECKED

   [image: IE Proxy 1]
3. Make sure "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" box is NOT CHECKED

   [image: IE Proxy 2]

Comment: Doesn't work. I not that do something or not there I look? [Screenshot](http://i79.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0601/5c/9177a9cafd26cb34d88318e0fd2f6e5c.png)

Comment: Try adding `log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy` line to *user.properties* file and restart JMeter. Than look for anything suspicious in *jmeter.log* file.

 As an alternative you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)